# Frame Buffer not Supported By this hardware. Java Processing library 2.2.1 and Unfolding Map Error

Tags: java, opengl, processing

I am trying to use **Unfolding Map** Library with **eclipse** with *Processing 2.2.1 as Graphics Library.* But this setup is giving me error like "Frame Buffer is not supported by this Hardware.."

```
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Framebuffer objects are not supported by this hardware (or driver) Read http://wiki.processing.org/w/OpenGL_Issues for help.
    at com.jogamp.common.util.awt.AWTEDTExecutor.invoke(AWTEDTExecutor.java:58)
    at jogamp.opengl.awt.AWTThreadingPlugin.invokeOnOpenGLThread(AWTThreadingPlugin.java:103)
    at jogamp.opengl.ThreadingImpl.invokeOnOpenGLThread(ThreadingImpl.java:206)
    at javax.media.opengl.Threading.invokeOnOpenGLThread(Threading.java:172)
    at javax.media.opengl.Threading.invoke(Threading.java:191)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.display(GLCanvas.java:541)
    at processing.opengl.PJOGL.requestDraw(PJOGL.java:688)
    at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.requestDraw(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:1651)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2256)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have AMD Radeon HD 7600 M Series Graphics Driver and its specs says that it supports OpenGl 4.2. I don't know what am i missing. Anybody Please Help.

Comment: you need to edit it as quickly as you can .. where you can save querry getting flagged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gives you a link directly in the error message: https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/OpenGL-Issues

That link lists many things you should try:

> - Try updating your graphics card drivers. If you're getting a blank screen with sketch that uses OpenGL, or the sketch is hanging or
>     starting very slowly, you likely need to update your drivers. On
>     Windows, updated drivers are available from your machine's vendor,
>     Windows Update, or the manufacturer of your graphics card. On Mac OS
>     X, use Software Update to make sure your system is up to date. On
>     Linux, try the non-free version of a driver.
> - On Windows, if you're getting a lot of OpenGL crashing, blue screens, or other mess, your driver might be bad (really!) For
>     instance, if you're using a Dell, use the driver they provide
>     (http://support.dell.com/) instead of what might be a more recent
>     driver obtained directly from http://nvidia.com.
> - If you're getting a blank screen or strange graphics on Windows, try messing with your graphics card settings (or even with a different
>     graphics card). There are lots of options that can cause trouble (if
>     you run into such a situation, please post to the forum on how you got
>     it fixed).
> - If you've recently updated, you may, on the other hand, need to downgrade your drivers. Sometimes experimental drivers (or the “free”
>     drivers on Linux) contain issues. Try different versions that might be
>     available for your system.
> - Almost all EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION crashes with OpenGL are driver problems, and we cannot fix them.
> - We don't recommend running other OpenGL programs while running Processing in OpenGL mode. GL tends takes charge of things so results
>     will be unexpected (windows from the other app showing through to the
>     Processing window, etc.)
> - The integrated graphics chipsets that Apple has been using on their "low end" machines (such Intel GMA 950) really stink for OpenGL. Some
>     don't support anti-aliasing at all. These cards are found in the Mac
>     Mini (the Intel version only, the PPC versions had nice graphics),
>     some iMacs, and the MacBook (but no the MacBook Pro). The same
>     chipsets are used in many budget PCs, to which the same disclaimer
>     applies.
> - The new version of the OpenGL library requires drivers that support OpenGL 2.0. This allows us to keep OpenGL support for desktop and
>     Android in sync with one another. Unfortunately this means that some
>     older cards and drivers (particularly on Linux) will not work, and
>     that Processing 2.0 on such machines will be limited to 2D graphics.
>     But the OpenGL library is developed by a single person (Andres
>     Colubri), who works on this in his free time, and he can't support two
>     separate video libraries with radically different implementations.
>     Keep in mind you can always use Processing 1.5.1 to continue 3D
>     development, though it will not be updated further, and we won't be
>     accepting bug reports for it.

If none of that works or explains your problem, then check out the known [OpenGL issues](https://github.com/processing/processing/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+opengl) listed on Processing's GitHub page.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I acted upon your advice and downloaded the Processing Sketch Book. Interestingly when i tried to use 3D or OPENGL renderer, just like i did before, it works! Everything Processing boast of doing works there. So i think the problem is with Java not being able to add OPENGL properly in eclipse environment. I have imported jogl-all JAR file, but with  no help. So if you could suggest something regarding Java and in particular regarding Eclipse then it will be very nice. Thanks.